# execfile() cannot be used reliably to modify a function’s locals

Tags: python, function, global, local, execfile

The python documentation states "execfile() cannot be used reliably to modify a function’s locals." on the page http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

Can anyone provide any further details on this statement? The documentation is fairly minimal. The statement seems very contradictory to "If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where execfile() is called." which is also in the documentation. Is there a special case when excecfile is used within a function then execfile is then acting similar to a function in that it creates a new scoping level?

If I use execfile in a function such as

```
def testfun():
    execfile('thefile.py',globals())
    def testfun2():
        print a
```

and there are objects created by the commands in 'thefile.py' (such as the object 'a'), how do I know if they are going to be local objects to testfun or global objects? So, in the function testfun2, 'a' will appear to be a global? If I omit globals() from the execfile statement, can anyone give a more detailed explanation why objects created by commands in 'thefile.py' are not available to 'testfun'?

Answer (score 6):

In Python, the way names are looked up is highly optimized inside functions. One of the side effects is that the mapping returned by `locals()` gives you a *copy* of the local names inside a function, and altering that mapping does not actually influence the function:

```
def foo():
    a = 'spam'
    locals()['a'] = 'ham'
    print(a)              # prints 'spam'
```

Internally, Python uses the `LOAD_FAST` opcode to look up the `a` name in the current frame *by index*, instead of the slower `LOAD_NAME`, which would look for a local name (by name), then in the `globals()` mapping if not found in the first.

The python compiler can only emit `LOAD_FAST` opcodes for local names that are known at *compile time*; but if you allow the `locals()` to directly influence a functions' locals then you cannot know all the local names ahead of time. Nested functions using scoped names (free variables) complicates matters some more.

In Python 2, you can force the compiler to switch off the optimizations and use `LOAD_NAME` always by using an `exec` statement in the function:

```
def foo():
    a = 'spam'
    exec 'a == a'         # a noop, but just the presence of `exec` is important
    locals()['a'] = 'ham'
    print(a)              # prints 'ham'
```

In Python 3, `exec` has been replaced by `exec()` and the work-around is gone. In Python 3 *all* functions are optimized.

And if you didn't follow all this, that's fine too, but that is why the documentation glosses over this a little. It is all due to an implementation detail of the CPython compiler and interpreter that most Python users do not need to understand; all you need to know that using `locals()` to change local names in a function does not work, usually.

Answer (score 1):

Locals are kind of weird in Python. Regular locals are generally accessed by index, not by name, in the bytecode (as this is faster), but this means that Python has to know all the local variables at compile time. And that means you can't add new ones at runtime.

Now, if you use `exec` in a function, in Python 2.x, Python knows not to do this and falls back to the slower method of accessing local variables by name, and you can make new ones programmatically. (This trick was removed in Python 3.) You'd think Python would also do this for `execfile()`, but it doesn't, because `exec` is a statement and `execfile()` is a function call, and the name `execfile` might not refer to the built-in function at runtime (it can be reassigned, after all).

What will happen in your example function? Well, try it and find out! As the documentation for `execfile` states, if you don't pass in a locals dict, the dict you pass in as globals will be used. You pass in `globals()` (your module's real global variables) so if it assigns to `a`, then `a` becomes a global.

Now you might try something like this:

```
def testfun():
    execfile('thefile.py')
    def testfun2():
        print a
    return testfun2
    exec ""
```

The `exec` statement at the end forces `testfun()` to use the old-style name-based local variables. It doesn't even have to be executed, as it is not here; it just has to be in the function somewhere.

But this doesn't work either, because the name-based locals don't support nesting functions with free variables (`a` in this case). That functionality *also* requires Python know all the local variables at function definition time. You can't even define the above function—Python won't let you.

In short, trying to deal with local variables programmatically is a pain and the documentation is correct: `execfile()` cannot reliably be used to modify a function's locals.

A better solution, probably, is to just `import` the file as a module. You can do this within the function, then access values in the module the usual way.

```
def testfun():
    import thefile
    print thefile.a
```

If you won't know the name of the file to be imported until runtime, you can use `__import__` instead. Also, you may need to modify `sys.path` to make sure the directory you want to import from is first in the path (and put it back afterward, probably).

You can also just pass in your own dictionary to `execfile` and afterward, access the variables from the executed file using `myVarsDict['a']` and so on.

Comment: your, as well as the answer provided by Martijn Pieters both describe issues with changing the local variables. maybe my question might be better posed saying why does execfile change local variables when run outside of a function? another question may be, why isn't there a simple include statement like in other languages that is just the equivalent to a copy and paste. this seems like a simple thing to do and i thought execfile would do it, but it doesn't.

Comment: actually, i did try it and if I run execfile('thefile.py',globals()) from within testfun, the objects created by 'thefile.py' are not available outside of testfun, but are available inside of testfun. this was a cause of my confusion (and that part of the question) because it seems like if execfile is run using globals(), the objects created should be global.